# SQL Query validation sent from .NET code to SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server

I maintain several .NET applications and services coded in c# that accesses SQL db for CRUD operations.

I want to ensure that each query that is sent to the database contains an important piece of the business logic, and if it is missing I want to fail the query.

I want to avoid a code solution (it doesn't matter why, that's just the way it is),
and I was wondering:

Is there a way for SQL server to intercept a query before execution for validation purposes, without affecting the query execution plan? 
You know, adding another bus stop in the "code to SQL" bus line?

**Clarification:**

I want the validation logic to be in a single place, written once (no duplicates) and applies to all queries.

**Another Clarification:**

Code solution would be acceptable if it would not require any modifications in my current DB Access infrastructure, and there is such existing written library without me needing to implement one.
I.e. like a "wrapping dll" that enables such functionality.

Comment: You can use Stored Procedures for Create, Update, Delete operations and Stored Procedures or Views - for Read operations. You can add any validations, assumptions and checks in them.

Comment: added clarification.

Comment: i get your question completely.you can definitely do it in c#, but  in reality i don't know if there any way to do the same in sql, but is there any problem if those all validations are done in query it self ??

Comment: I don't think you can add a like a handler in SQL.  Even if you could do you  have a parser to evaluate the query?

Comment: Just read that SSIS package has a PreExecute handler, so I'm looking into it.

Answer (score 0):

The only restrictions you can made in sql are permissions and grants.

> There is no mechanism to restrict what is being executed from a login.

**It is just like thinking to restrict  ssh tunnel running for certain commands only.**

The Possible solution is you can do the validation inside your query.

Or write a common function for validating all the inputs to sql server in C# based on your validation criteria s